# Options for packing/unpacking several strings for transmission via a byte[] parameter

Tags: android

I've got several strings I want to send to a wearable app via the MessageApi.sendMessage method, which just takes a byte[] parameter to carry the payload.

I could concatenate all the strings together and introduce some arbitrary separating character sequence then convert the result to bytes and do the reverse to unpack it on the watch.

But I was wondering if there's a ready-made solution for such a thing in Android (or Java)?

Comment: you could use a `DataOutputStream`. It allows to write String to a stream, which can be a bytearrayoutputstream, and on the other side you can use a `DataInputStream` to read the strings back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, `Data*Stream` are made for that:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream data = new DataOutputStream(byteStream);
data.writeUTF("Whatever string you have here");
data.writeUTF("Write any number of strings");
byte[] result = byteStream.toByteArray();
```

On the other side:

```
byte[] myBytes = ...; // Retrieve the bytes through MessageApi
ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myBytes);
DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(byteStream);
String str1 = data.readUTF();
// That would be "Whatever string you have here"
String str2 = data.readUTF();
// And "Write any number of strings"
```

That's that simple. Since those are byte[] back streams, there is no need to close them.

Comment: Thanks, whats the standard way of dealing with if any of the strings are null?

Comment: I don't think writeUTF handles null at all.

Comment: I get compilation errors, each instance of writeUTF() generates. "error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown". At first I thought it was the compiler being smart and detecting that the String variable I was passing might be null, but if I replace the String variable with a quoted string, as in your example, the compilation still fails. Does use of this API mandate the use of try/catch block in conjunction with it?

Comment: IOException is thrown by DataOutputStream because it relies on another stream on which it has no control. Typically this can happen if you use it over a network connection. You need to catch it, but it is very unlikely that it will ever be thrown.

Comment: How can this be extended to additionally write a bitmap to the data stream?

Comment: there are a few options. a bitmap is parcelable, so you could create a parcel, put your bitmap in it, get the equivalent byte[], do the inverse process on the other side. If you have a file, writing the file directly to the stream would be more efficient (because the file is usually compressed while the bitmap is not).